# Remove spaces in table cell

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I am using MS Word I need to display two pictures next to each other. For this I created the table shown in the image below. However, I cannot find any way to fit the image to the table cell. I have every single margin set to zero. I've tried changing the column height manually. I have tried all possible image align options. However nothing seems to work. There is always the "cell marker" there taking up all that space.

Is there any way to reduce the row height to better fit my content?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fit of the image inside the table cell actually depends on multiple factors:

1. Cell margins
2. "Before" and "After" spacing of the paragraph within the cell
3. Line spacing of the paragraph within the cell

It looks like you are trying to achieve a similar look like in this [video](https://youtu.be/yKgafEAkuJo?si=DlmimKrYP6IcNvlV&t=31).
If you follow the explanations from 0:31 to 3:00 you should be good. In the end, this portion of the video is about the mentioned 3 points but maybe the other info in the video also helps.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't exactly what I needed, but it pointed me in the right direction. I also found this video just in case anyone comes looking for an answer later: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAfVxTF5ceM&t=159s Feel free to add it to your answer if you think it'll help others